# Selenium - Click on an item with text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
<li class="search-choice" id="elementID">
<span>TEST.SER</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-choice-close" rel="53"></a></li>
```

And it shows like this:

[image]

And I want to perform a click on the X of the elements, but having in count the name without the ID.I trying this but without to get it:

```
   "test2": (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='search-choice-close' and contains(text(), 'TEST.SER')]"),
    "test3": (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='search-choice-close']//span[contains(text(),'TEST.SER')]"),
    "test": (By.XPATH,"//li[@class='search-choice']//span[contains(text(),'TEST.SER')]//a[ @class ='search-choice-close']")
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: From Review: Your image link is broken, please edit your question and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below XPath

```
//span[text()='TEST.SER']/following::a
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.

Ajitav's solution did not work for me.

But your solution yes, DishantB, thank you very much.

I didn't know the use of following. Do you always take the next thing you put? Can you explain me a little?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on how we are drilling down the object location using other object's reference. You may like to have a look in to xpath axes concepts.https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Text() TEST.SER and class="search-choice-close" are not in same hierarchy so the option 1 would not work.

option 2 hierarchy created by your locator is wrong. span is above a tag

option 3 you are trying to click on the li element instead of the href. So it would not work.

Try By.XPATH(//a[@class='search-choice-close']/parent::span[contains(text(),'TEST.SER')]) if you want to click on the text.

If you want to click on the image just use By.XPATH(//a[@class='search-choice-close'])

Answer (score 0):

The reason your xpaths are not finding the correct element is because they are looking for attributes of both the span and a tags either as if they were the same element, or as if one was imbedded inside of the other. You will need to instead find the span element, and then find the sibling a element that follows it.

Reasons for your issues:

```
"test2": (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='search-choice-close' and contains(text(), 'TEST.SER')]")
```

Here you are looking for an a element that contains the proper class of the a element, but the text of the span element

```
"test3": (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='search-choice-close']//span[contains(text(),'TEST.SER')]")
```

Here you are looking for the span element as if it existed within the a element, but it does not exist within the a element, but along side it

```
"test": (By.XPATH,"//li[@class='search-choice']//span[contains(text(),'TEST.SER')]//a[ @class ='search-choice-close']")
```

Here you are doing the same as above, looking for an a element within the span element. The elements are not descendants or ancestors of each other, but rather siblings.

What you need to do is find the sibling element to the span element, if you need to look for the a element using the text of the span before it.

```
//span[text()='TEST.SER']/following::a
```

Here is some more information on the hierarchy of elements in the DOM that might be useful for you to go over the next time you are having issues locating elements through Xpath.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp